# How to encrypt a file?

Tags: encryption, php, file-encryption, c++

I created my own encrypt / decrypt script and I can encrypt any kind of strings. I just need to know how can I use my script to encrypt a file like an image or a text file?

My script is working in PHP, C++ and VB.

Comment: This is a programming question, despite being about encryption, so would be better suited to stackoverflow. Please be aware that home-built encryption methods are generally considered to be a bad idea due to lacking peer review over a long period.

Comment: @Matthw thx for the suggestion :)

Comment: Please do not migrate this to Stack Overflow. In it's current form it is to broad and will just be closed there. @Soheyl If you want help on Stack Overflow, you will need to ask a much more detailed and specific question. And you need to try something yourself, not just ask for the code. Read the Help Center over there before you ask.

Comment: @Anders Thx for the info, but what can be more info about my question ? or when I had no idea, what could I do myself ? I already got my answer so I think my question was already good to get an answer !

Comment: I do wonder what kind of encryption algorithm can only handle text and not binary...

Comment: I agree that this question should not be migrated, but not because it deals with programming. Wring your own encryption/decryption script sounds eerily similar to rolling your own crypto algorithms. Don't be a Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be very basic: 
Encode file to base64, encrypt it, sent it to target, decrypt with your script to base64 and decode the base64 to a image file. But this has nothing to do with informaction security. Move to StackOverflow is better.

Comment: If you think a question is off topic, please don't post an answer.

Comment: Please don't suggest moving questions like these to Stack Overflow. The question doesn't show research effort, doesn't show code.... sending it to SO in its current form is just going to get it downvoted into oblivion. It should be toroughly improved before it's a candidate for migration.

Comment: True @S.L.Barth, sorry.

Comment: @Anders i think its a good question. I was doubting if security.stackexchange.com was the best exchange to ask this.